# converting rewrite rules apache to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, nginx

I have a php symfony project, where I am removing apache as a server, and using nginx for performance reasons.
No in my virtualhost.conf i have the following settings

```
<Directory "/usr/share/myvirtualhost/web">
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-DEVELOP-DOC-TEST} ^running$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_doctest.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Now I have no idea how to convert this to proper nginx rewrite rules, especially the part with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-DEVELOP-DOC-TEST} ^running$
```

where I am checking if a header is being set, to forward the request to `app_doctest.php`

How can I get further from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are some links to search in the right directions.

Start with that : [a full doc on how to convert things from apache in the right way](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/).

And that mean, for example, that you will not use rewrites but `try_files` instead.

Then for specific headers tests you can use the `http_` form, your `X-DEVELOP-DOC-TEST` header should be in the `http_x_develop_doc_test` variable. Avoid `if` structures and prefer `map` or such.